# Is there an upper limit on the x-delay header in RabbitAMQ's delayed message plugin?

Tags: rabbitmq

We have a use case for very long delays on RabbitMQ messages in some situations (potentially > 50 days). Is there an upper limit to what a delayed exchange can handle for `x-delay`ed messages? Presumably there is some performance cost to very long running timers, but for the purposes of this question that's not an issue.

Comment: I suggest you ask this on the [rabbitmq-users google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users) - that's where the RabbitMQ engineers hang out. The question is not really related to `spring-amqp`.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll remove that tag.